# STL error _without_ any STL in code

Tags: c++, namespaces, g++, cygwin, using

I am using gcc 3.4.4 on cygwin.  I am getting this rather perplexing STL error message in my code below which does not use STL at all:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

const int N = 100;

bool s[N + 1];
bool p[N + 1];
bool t[N + 1];

void find(const bool a[], bool b[], bool c[]){
  return;
}


int main(){
  find(s, p, t);
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile with 
    g++ stack.cc

I get the following error message:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h: In function `_RandomAccessIterator std::find(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, const _Tp&, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = bool*, _Tp = bool[101]]':
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:314:   instantiated from `_InputIterator std::find(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const _Tp&) [with _InputIterator = bool*, _Tp = bool[101]]'
stack.cc:18:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:207: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:211: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:215: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:219: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:227: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:231: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:235: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer
```

As you can see, the code does not use any STL at all, so this is rather strange. Also, the error disappears if I remove the line

```
using namespace std;
```

which hints at some namespace clash.  It also disappears if I remove the `const` keyword from the definition o the function `find`.

On the other had the error *also* disappears (and this is rather surprising) if I make `find` a 2-argument function as follows:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

const int N = 100;

bool s[N + 1];
bool p[N + 1];
bool t[N + 1];

void find(const bool a[], bool b[]){
  return;
}


int main(){
  find(s, p);
  return 0;
}
```

I can't imagine what could be the reason why find can be a two argument function but not a three argument one.

So here is a brief summary of the three ways to remove the error:

1. Remove the `using namespace std;` line.
2. Remove the `const` keyword from the definition of `find`.
3. Remove the third argument of the function `find`.

I cannot think of any logical reason why such an error should happen in the first place, and why it should get removed i I use any of the above seemingly completely unrelated steps.  Is this a documented g++ bug? I tried searching for it, but honestly I was at a loss what to search for, and the few keywords I tried ("STL error without STL use") didn't turn up anything.

Comment: By the way, in C++ there isn't really a thing called STL, which stands for Standard Template Library. There is an old STL, but nobody uses it anymore because way back after it was made, most of it was *adopted* into the Standard Library. While `<algorithm>` may have originated from the STL, it's not really correct to say using it is using the STL. Both `<iostream>` and `<algorithm>` are part of the Standard Library. Hence your confusion: you *are* using the Standard Library (`<iostream>`), which may involve `<algorithm>`.

Comment: Well, I used to think that STL (at least currently) is just the partly unofficial name given to the part of the standard library which predominantly deals with providing template-based structures and algorithms. But yes, I somehow did have the subconscious idea that the STL part of the library is somehow "secondary" to the older parts of the library, such as `iostream`.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply have a collision, because you've unintentionally pulled `std::find` (which takes 3 arguments) into the global namespace when you did `using namespace std;`.  For whatever reason, your `<iostream>` is `#include`-ing `<algorithm>`, or one of the parts of its internal implementation (specifically, `bits/stl_algo.h`).

I can't explain why removing `const` makes it go away; perhaps it affects the order in which the compiler resolves overloads.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.  Though I still do not understand why `algorithm` would be included by `iostream`.

Comment: @CirceMagnifica: Me neither.  I don't think the standard prohibits it, though.

Comment: It's definitely allowed to do that. The key thing to take away from this in my view is that `using namespace std;` is a bad habit to fall into.

Comment: Also, perhaps the reason for the version without the `const` working is, as I said in another comment below: the `InputIterator` type required by `std::find` would match with a non-const pointer but not with a `const` pointer?

Comment: When you have `const` it requires *two* conversion to call your function: array to pointer (`bool[101]` -> `bool*`), then qualification conversion (`bool*` -> `const bool*`). The template argument for `std::find` is deduced to match exactly, so requires no conversions. (Both array to pointer and qualification adjustment conversions are ranked as exact matches, but not if you need more than one IIRC.) Once you remove the `const`, that second conversion is not required; you have an exact match with array to pointer, and it's preferred over the template exact match, because it's not a template.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the sequences of type-matching explanation, GManNickG.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the compiler with the version of find that is in the standard library (std::find), which has 3 parameters, but not the ones you have.

If your code was in its own namespace, you could avoid this problem.  Or by renaming your find method, or the solutions you have already documented.

Comment: Yes, I think as long as my first `bool` array is not `const`, it its in with the `std::find` version (I guess since the `InputIterator` type would match with a non-const pointer but not with a `const` pointer?).  Thanks for the answer (which I unfortunately, can't upvote :().